# Java FX ListView cell background affect uncolored cells while scrolling

Tags: java, javafx

**Problem :** I'm using a ListView in Java Fx , once the cell met a certain condition it's colored .
[Cells met condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYdPd.png)
Once I scroll up and down through the list, the background color goes to all the other cells, even when they didn't met the condition.
[All cells colored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Bti.png)

I know that it have to do with the behavior of the ListView , as it recycle the cells and some attributes, looks like that background cells is one of them.
The condition is one way, once it's colored, it won't be uncolored.

It check the condition every X time or when pressing a button.

Snip of the code :
Where I set the CellFactory

```
groupCheckListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView, ListCell>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell call(ListView param) {
            return new ChangeColor();
        }
    });




// Change cell color
class ChangeColor extends ListCell<String> {
@Override
protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {

    if (empty || item == null) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else if (item.toLowerCase().endsWith("done")) {
        setText(item);
        // Fill the "done" cell with color -> "#58FF2D" = light green
        setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Paint.valueOf("#58FF2D"), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
    } else {
        setText(item);
    }

    super.updateItem(item, empty);

}
```

CSS File

```
.list-cell:empty {
-fx-background-color: white;
}
```

If there are any other suggestions , some things missing or to explain better, just say so.

Thanks =]

Comment: You set the background to green, when the item ends with "done", but you don't set it to white otherwise. You need to actively reset the background, meaning setting it to white, when it's not supposed to be green.

Comment: I recommend using a css stylesheet to apply the style. (Un)set a pseudoclass in the `updateItem` method. This allows you to modify the background color based on your criterion ***and*** the selection state and also allows you to "go back to the standard look" once the pseudoclass is removed. If you set the `background` to a different value, even to `null`, this assignment has a higher priority than the css stylesheet used for the normal look. This way you won't get back to the exact same style the cell had initially and selected cells also won't be highlighted.